# servicestack-dart How to check if a session already exists?

Tags: flutter, dart, servicestack

currently I am developing an app with service stack, the thing is that after an user logs itself, thenplaces the app in the background and when the OS kills the app for resources and you return to the foreground, the app will restart and place the app in the root route, the thing is that there is no method that can tell us if there was an existing session before. I have already tried to check the access token and bearer properties after the login process itself and the come null. Is there any way I could solve this?

I am using servicestack-dart 1.0.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your [JsonServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-dart/blob/master/lib/client.dart) doesn't have any BearerToken, Credentials or Cookies configured then it can only make unauthenticated requests.

If it is configured, you can send an empty `Authenticate` DTO where it will return an `AuthenticateResponse` with basic session info if the client instance is authenticated, e.g:

```
var authResponse = await client.post(new Authenticate());
```

Otherwise it will throw a `WebServiceException` with **Unauthorized** `errorCode`.

For auth examples have a look at [servicestack](https://pub.dev/packages/servicestack) client Auth Tests:

- [client_auth_test.dart](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-dart/blob/master/test/client_auth_test.dart)
- [test_auth_test.dart](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-dart/blob/master/test/test_auth_test.dart)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my JsonServiceClient uses the providers: "credentials" configuration, so I way to solve my issue would be to store the credentials somewhere and send another request in order to preserve the session of last logged user?